# get an array of meta tags php

Tags: php, html, arrays, meta-tags

How can I get all of the values from the `<meta>` named "tag" and echo them on the page?

this is the HTML im using:

```
<meta name="tag" content="plant"/>
<meta name="tag" content="leaf"/>
<meta name="tag" content="waterdroplet"/>
<meta name="tag" content="water"/>
```

PHP that im using:

```
$tags = array (get_meta_tags ( "http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/background-garage/?p=photo&photo=1"));
echo $tags;
```

The result is that it only echos the last `<meta>` named "tag".

Comment: Of course - you always overwrite the tag named ``tag`` ;-) - you have only one value - which is the latest one.

Answer (score 3):

`get_meta_tags` returns an array, use `print_r()` to see it's structure, and loop through them to print them however you want:

```
foreach($tags as $tag){
  echo $tag."\n";
}
```

Edit: And you don't need to stick the restult of `get_meta_tags` in another array, then you just have an extra one for no reason.

```
explode(',',$meta['tags']);
```

Comment: It's separated by newlines, look at the source code to see the recursion more clearly. If it's just an array in an array then `get_meta_tags` isn't doing what you expect it to, seeing what thedom said, try putting all the tags in a comma separated string, then `split()` it later.

Comment: @J V split() is deprecated in ver. 5.3.0. is there any alternative?

Comment: Ah yes, `explode()` - my bad, bit of something else creeping into my php :)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is now **how would I get comma-separated values as different tags?**, you could do something like this:

```
<meta name="tag" content="plant, leaf, waterdroplet, water" />

$tags = get_meta_tags('yourfile.html');
$tags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags['tag']));
```

This will explode the words into an array, and remove any whitespace, you can then loop over this for outputting/whatever else:

**example**

```
foreach($tags as $k => $v) {
  echo $k . ': ' . $v . '<br />' . "\n";
}
```

Would output:

```
0: plant
1: leaf
2: waterdroplet
3: water
```

Comment: how could I make this into a search that gets the tags and shows the results?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the tags correctly, but not displaying them correctly.

You can't use `echo` on an array.

You can use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see the whole array that you have - which should show you how to access it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake in setting the tags

```
<meta name="tag" content="xx" />
<meta name="tag" content="yz" />
```

When you execute `get_meta_tags()` on that, it will only show you the **last** value (in that case: `yz`)

So you need to put different names on the tags

eg

```
<meta name="tag1" content="yz" />
<meta name="tag2" content="yz" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The names must be unique. [See the documentation of this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php):

```
 If two meta tags have the same name, only the last one is returned.
```

So you can only have on meta-tag with name="tag", so better try a comma separated value for that.

Comment: How would I get the comma separated values as different tags?

Comment: I would use `<meta name="tags" content="water,leaf,plant" />` but it depends on what you will need the meta tag for.